# How to mix boost::bind with C function pointers to implement callbacks

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to shoehorn in some boost::bind to substitute member functions for straight up C function pointer style callbacks, but I'm running into problems doing the obvious thing.  Can someone tell me why the following code snippet can't seem to match up the types in the function call?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
  Foo(const string &prefix) : prefix_(prefix) {}
  void bar(const string &message)
  {
    cout << prefix_ << message << endl;
  }
private:
  const string &prefix_;
};

static void
runit(void (*torun)(const string &message), const string &message)
{
  torun(message);
}

int
main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  Foo foo("Hello ");
  runit(boost::bind<void>(&Foo::bar, boost::ref(foo), _1), "World!");
}
```

Comment: Why would you do this? What benefit are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AJG85 - I have a C library that is used by multiple C programs (which precludes me from modifying the headers/implementation) and I want to develop a new C++ program using some of the provided functionality.  In particular there are places where I want to call one of a possible set of library functions (with identical signatures save the function name) through a generic callback mechanism.

Comment: Ah well a typedef of a `boost::function` and a function that takes a `const&` to the typedef in a namespace ought to work if you must. Then you can use `boost::bind` when calling the namespace function with whatever you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result type of `bind` is not a function pointer, it's a function *object* which does not happen to be implicitly convertible to a function pointer. Use a template:

```
template<typename ToRunT>
void runit(ToRunT const& torun, std::string const& message)
{
    torun(message);
}
```

Or use [`boost::function<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/function/index.html):

```
static void runit(boost::function<void(std::string const&)> const& torun,
                  std::string const& message)
{
    torun(message);
}
```

Comment: The actual term for it is `bind_expression` (see the related [is_http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb981965.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb981965.aspx) mpl predicate)

Comment: Tested both of these methods and they worked just fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than having a specific function pointer signature for your first argument to `runit`, use a template.  So for instance:

```
template<typename function_ptr>
void runit(function_ptr torun, const string &message)
{
  torun(message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use boost::function type for boost::bind objects

Answer (score 0):

Pasting the error you get could be useful; however at a guess it's probably due to the fact that `"World!"` is a string literal (i.e. `char[]`), not a `std::string`. Try:

```
runit(boost::bind<void>(&Foo::bar, boost::ref(foo)), std::string("World!"));
```

Comment: implicit conversion will take place via copy constructor overloads on `std::string`